# InitErgmTerm.graphletCount in R

Tags: r

I loaded my interaction data, converted to an adjacency matrix and then converted it to an undirected graph.

I installed the packages; `ergm`, `ergm.graphlets`, `statnet`, etc.

When I write:

```
InitErgmTerm.graphletCount(GY2)
```

I get the following error message:

> Error: is.directed(nw) :  is.directed requires an argument of **class
>   network**.

I couldn't find a solution in the tutorial, and I would really appreciate if someone clarifies this.

Comment: Normally users should never need to write 'InitErgmTerm' anything, as all of that is handled by higher-level ergm functions.  Can you include some example code?  Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do a graphletCount then the way to do it is within an 'ergm()' command, as follows:

```
ergm(GY2~graphletCount(n))
```

n can be any number from 0 to 29 corresponding to the 30 possible graphlets that exist with up to 5 nodes. It's also possible to define a vector 'c(1,3,5)' to run the graphletCount. Be aware that n is an optional argument and can be left blank, which will run all 30 possible counts.

See the [paper on ergm.graphlets for examples](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.7348.pdf)